# Cant use Functions in one file in another

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, uiviewcontroller

I created a file called "Util.swift"  and it has a class "class VC: UIViewController" and has a 2 functions:

```
Next(segue: String) {
    performSegueWithIdentifier(segue, completion: nil)
}

Back() {
    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

So basically, the functions just tell the current viewController to go to the next View or go back to the previous view.

However, in another file, I have an IBAction which is attached to a button and in that action I call the function "Back" in the Util file by doing this:

```
@IBACTION func ~~~ {
    nextVC = Util()
    nextVC.back()
}
```

However, when I click the button, it doesn't do anything.

When I try to connect another button to an action that calls the "next" function in the Util file by doing the same thing and putting in the segue indetifier parameter, it says SIGABRT error: no segue identifier called "xxx".

Can anyone help me? Should I simply use XIB and not use segues?

Comment: why are you putting these functions in another class?  The reason that the segue can't be found is that you are just creating Util using an initialiser rather than from a storyboard, so it has no connection to the storyboard.

Comment: @Paulw11, you should flesh your comment out a little bit and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the `UIViewController` either with `storyBoard` or with `XIB`. If you are doing with factory `init()` method then it doesn't do anything for you; that means, that is not a `viewController` which is associated either with `storyBoard` or `XIB`. So all you need to do is instantiate the viewController with either options. Before that you need to set an `identifier` for the `viewController` to instantiate it.

```
let storyBoard = UIStoryBoard(name: "MainStoryBoard", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyBoard.instanstiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YOUR_IDENTIFIER") as! Util
//call your Next method like this
vc.Next(segue:"identifier")
```

Please refer the document
[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH15-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

In order to use segues, the view controller instance needs to be associated with a Storyboard.  In order to be associated with a storyboard, a view controller instance either needs to be the result of a segue or instantiated from a storyboard via `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier`.

When you create an instance of `Util` via `Util()` you have a view controller instance that isn't associated with a storyboard and isn't actually presented on screen.

As a result, when you try and perform a segue, you get an error since the segue can't be found.

Also, when you try and dismiss the view controller in `back()` you are trying to dismiss a view controller that isn't presented.

I am not sure why you want to wrap two fairly simple functions inside `next` and `back`, but you can do this using a superclass for all of your view controllers and have this superclass implement your `next` and `back` functions:

```
class MyViewContollerSuperclass: UIViewController {

    func next(segue: String) {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier(segue, sender: self)
    }

    func back() {
        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

Then you actual view controller would be declared as:

```
   class MyActualViewController: MyViewContollerSuperclass {

       @IBACTION func ~~~ {
           self.back()
       }
   }
```

Comment: I have a quite a few storyboards and have "back" and "next" buttons on each view. I didn't want to type "perfromsegue" and "dismissViewController" over and over again, so i created the "next" and "back".